# Performance of count queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am working on a MySQL database (Amazon RDS) and have a table with about 2.800.000 rows.

I need the count of all rows. So I issue

```
select count(*) from data_sample
```

But this (hell simple) query takes more than a minute ?!? Is this possible?

**EDIT** Here is the explained output:

```
explain select count(*) from data_sample
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data_sample | NULL       | index | NULL          | IDX_91F547DA98AFEB75 | 5       | NULL | 2800632 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.14 sec)
```

I cannot duplicate this dataset so quickly, but is it possible that the same query is much more efficient on a postgres db?

Comment: Did you tried `EXPLAIN select count(*) from data_sample` ? And what if you do `select count(id) from data_sample` ? Is it faster using some index ?

Comment: I added the `explain` output

Comment: `select count(*) from data_sample` is slow on InnoDB ... @MickaëlLeger no index will change that..

Comment: @RaymondNijland it was a question :) so the answer is no !

Comment: Also `select count(id) from data_sample` will not matter @MickaëlLeger if you are looking into the explain the `SELECT COUNT(*)` MySQL already does a FULL index scan -> `type: Index Extra: Using index` indicates that with a high number of estimated number of records.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying count query in postgres works faster than mysql. If so, you are right. You may check this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149729/mysql-vs-postgresql-benchmarking-count-execution-speed

Answer (score 1):

**Talking about the performance (MYSQL)**

Firstly You would need proper indexing for everything to execute in the most efficient way.

When you `COUNT(*)` it takes in count column indexes, so it will give the fastest results. Mysql with **MyISAM** engine stores row count and doesn't count all rows each time you try `count`.

If the `COUNT(*)` is slow, you should run `EXPLAIN` on the query, and check if indexes are really used, and where should they be added.

> **MyISAM** stores row count. Other storage engines like **InnoDB** do not store row counts and will count all rows each time and would be slow.

Index everything properly, make sure the indexes are being used and the query would give the best result possible.

For more details on Indexing read [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

**Regarding RDS**

The performance and response time would also depend upon the type of RDS instance you are using depending upon the capacity.

**Regarding comparison to Postgresql**

Postgres has different ways to do things in comparison to mysql. Go through [this](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/) blog to understand it more with examples.